# CAC USB reader not allowing authentication, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, certificates, smartcard

I am with the US government and use certificates on a "CAC" smart card to authenticate on web sites. I have a USB smart card reader (SMC Microsystems), which is detected by the OS, but the sites I visit (FireFox 84.0.2 and Chromium 88.0.4234.96) don't see the certificate to authenticate.  Thoughts?

```
brendan@b-Tron:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5621 IMC Networks EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e6:5814 SCM Microsystems, Inc. SCR3500 A Contact Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't have direct access to certificates in smart card or USB Tokens.  You may need to use Browser extension to access certificates from smartcard.  Is there any method suggested by the site, you want to authenticate?

Example of Browser Extension for digital signing or authentication or encryption/decryption on browser side is Signer.Digital extension. Please check by searching on Signer.Digital extension if it helps.